# Gracefully close applications on shutdown

Tags: command-line, shutdown, wmctrl

How to automatically close an application on shutdown (graceful close, not kill)?

I try to call `wmctrl -c "App"` in `powerbtn.sh`, but it does not work. The same `wmctrl` command works perfectly when typed in terminal or called from a script without superuser rights.

Why does it not work in `powerbtn.sh` and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

A normal shutdown gracefully closes all processes anyway - that is, it calls SIGTERM on them, then waits for them to terminate - SIGTERM being the normal way of telling a process to close and allowing it to do any clean-up work necessary before actually terminating.

That is, you don't need to worry about doing this.